# Taylor serie convergence and holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a doubt related to holomorphic functions and the convergence of their Taylor series. Is it true that:

"if and only if $f(z)$ is holomorphic in D (open), then Taylor expansion of $f(z)$ in D converges to $f(z)$ for all $z \in D$"

In other words, is it possible to have a function with poles in D, where its regular Taylor converges to $f(z)$ for some $z \in D$  but not necessarily for all?

A strong reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $D$ any open set? and which Taylor expansion are you talking about?

Comment: From my question I assume D is a disc. Taylor series is centered in the middle of the Disc.

Comment: that would be good to put in the statement; you only told us $D$ was open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

> $f:D\to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic if and only if the Taylor expansion of $f$ converges to $f(z)$ for every $z\in D$.

is true.

For the $\implies$ direction, you can use the Cauchy integral formula.

For the $\impliedby$ direction I don't know any relevant reference, but it seems quite straightforward that if you assume that the Taylor series of the function converges for every $z$, then the function is at least differentiable (hence holomorphic) for every $z$.

The central part of the issue is the first statement, which is nicely proven in Theorem 10.16 of the third edition of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

You should check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573984/difference-between-analytic-and-holomorphic-function) question to understand why the concept of analytic and holomorphic functions were born even though they ultimately identify the same functions over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: you can no imagine how much appreciate your answer.   If you could point to any reference in a classical/prestigious book I would appreciate it even more.

Comment: Are you assuming $D$ is a disc? And where is this Taylor series centered?

Comment: From my question I assume D is a disc. Taylor series is centered in the middle of the Disc.

Comment: @abr I added a reference for the main implication of the statement.